# Liquibase with MySQL causes 'Table 'databasechangelog' already exists' error

Tags: mysql, maven, liquibase

I am trying to migrate from MariaDB to MySQL. When running liquibase a second time with maven i get the following error:

`Table 'databasechangelog' already exists`

This is the maven plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.23.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <changeLogFile>changelog.mysql.sql</changeLogFile>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</url>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>password</password>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.33</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Does liquibase not check if the table exists? I found some similar problems where case sensitivity seems to be the cause. My DB schema is set to `lower_case_table_names=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new database schema fixed the problem. The mysql space should not be used anyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).